# postgres & psycopg server-side cursor: will data be locked?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, cursor, psycopg2

I want to to use psycopg to create a server-side cursor to my postgres DB so that I can read a very large table

```
cursor = conn.cursor('name_of_the_new_server_side_cursor')
cursor.execute(""" SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10000000 """)

while True:
    rows = cursor.fetchmany(5000)
    if not rows:
        break

    for row in rows:
        # do something with row
        pass
```

While I iterate through the large table, pulling out data, can rows be updated or added by another process/query while my query runs?  If so, as my cursor iterates through the table, will it see update/new data or data as it was when the query was initially executed?  For example, say as I pull the first 50k rows of data, an update is made to row 51201.  When my cursor then moves down to pull data from rows 50,000 to 55000, will my query return the row in its updated form or original form?  If a new row is added by another process, will my query return the new row or return the table in its state when I first ran the cursor.execute statement?

Answer (score 0):

[The Documentation regarding autocommit says:](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.autocommit)

> By default, any query execution, including a simple SELECT will start a transaction: for long-running programs, if no further action is taken, the session will remain “idle in transaction”, an undesirable condition for several reasons (locks are held by the session, tables bloat…).

So selects will have the same locks as every other transaction.

If you are just pulling to read the data, you could try fixing it by setting:

```
conn.set_session(readonly=True, autocommit=True)
```

But if you are looking to process/update the data you might be better off doing it in a stored proc within the database, depending on what exactly you are looking to do.